# ValueError: substring not found, What am I doing wrong?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def get_file():
  lst_Filename = []
  while True:
    Filename = input('\nPlease enter name of ballot file: ')
    try:    
        read_Filename = open(Filename, 'r')
        txt_Filename = read_Filename.readlines()
        lst_Filename = [word.strip() for word in txt_Filename]
        read_Filename.close()
        return lst_Filename
    except IOError:
        print("The file",Filename,"does not exist.")
        continue


lst_Filename = get_file()
lst2 = {}
for item in lst_Filename:
    if item.index('1') == 0:
        print(item)
```

The lst_Filename is structured as follows: ['1490 2 Mo', '1267 3 Mo', '2239 6 Mo', '1449 7 Ks'], the actual file contains hundreds of items in the list.

I am trying to select the item that begins with '1'. When I run the program, the first two items is printed

```
1490 2 Mo

1267 3 Mo
```

then I get the ValueError: substring not found, it says the problem is with the line "if item.index('1') == 0:", i assume because '2239 6 Mo' does not begin with '1'

What I don't understand is that my codes says for every item in the lst_Filename, if that item(which is a string) has the substring '1' in its 0 index then select the item.

Isn't the 'if' a selection statement, why doesn't the program skips through items that don't begin with '1'.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem with this is that `.index()` throws `ValueError` when it does not find the requested item. This is why it works for the first two items, but when it reaches a string that starts with something other than `1`, it dumps an error and stops searching. To make what you want to do work you should use `str.startswith()`.

Demo:

```
>>> lst = ['1490 2 Mo', '1267 3 Mo', '2239 6 Mo', '1449 7 Ks']
>>> [item for item in lst if item.startswith('1')]
['1490 2 Mo', '1267 3 Mo', '1449 7 Ks']
```

Answer (score 33):

item.index('1') is raising an exception because '1' is not found in the string (https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.index). Try to use item.find('1') instead!

Comment: item.find('1') will equally fail if '1' is not present within the string

Comment: It will return -1, but won't raise any exception.

Answer (score 4):

`item.index('1')` returns the index in your list where `'1'` is found. However, `'1'` is not in your example list at all. Your question states that you're "trying to select the item that begins with `'1'`." Begins with `"1"` and equals `"1"` are not the same thing. Your requirement is itself potentially problematic, as you say `"item,"` singular, but in fact three items in your list begin with `"1"`.

If you want to find all the items in a list that begin with `"1"`, you can use a list comprehension, like so:

```
[item for item in lst_Filename if item.startswith('1')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, this does the trick:

```
phrase = "A man, a plan, a canal, Panama!"
portion = "Panama"

if portion.lower() in phrase.lower():
    # ...
else:
    # ...
```