# Python str.index()

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I am using Python 3.5.2. I took the following code from interactivepython website but when I test it to my IDLE (I saved it as a script, save->run) it throws a `ValueError: substring not found`

I replaced `.index` with `.find` and it worked but still the question remains...
I know that `str.index()` does throw an error if it can't find anything. I am wondering if the code is correct, what am I missing here?

```
def encrypt(message, cipher):
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    encrypted = ''
    for char in message:
        if char == ' ':
            encrypted = encrypted + ' '
        else:
            pos = alphabet.index(char)
            encrypted = encrypted + cipher[pos]
    return encrypted
```

Comment: What should `pos` be when `char` is, say, the capital letter C? Or an exclamation point? Or a carriage return? If you're thinking "my message doesn't contain any of those", it would be helpful if you showed us what your message _does_ contain.

Comment: Better you should read this "Answer" from other post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22747288/4479481)

Comment: You are missing the knowledge to interpret the Exception that has been raised - what exception does ```str.index``` raise?  You also seem to be missing a [method for diagnosing exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions)

Comment: @kevin i got a good answer below  i accepted. My input for the code was: phrase1 = " I was walking down." By using the code below from woockashek ,  it is hard for me to see why 'I' and the dot sign in phrase1 are causing error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could easily check out what you are missing by handling exception you get as follows:

```
def encrypt(message, cipher):                                                                                                                                                                                   
    alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"                                                                                                                                                                     
    encrypted = ''                                                                                                                                                                                              
    for char in message:                                                                                                                                                                                        
        if char == ' ':                                                                                                                                                                                         
            encrypted = encrypted + ' '                                                                                                                                                                         
        else:                                                                                                                                                                                                   
            try:                                                                                                                                                                                                
                pos = alphabet.index(char)                                                                                                                                                                      
                encrypted = encrypted + cipher[pos]                                                                                                                                                             
            except ValueError:                                                                                                                                                                                  
                print "I'm not handling correctly the '{}' character".format(char)                                                                                                                              

    return encrypted
```

Now you will get the right log printed for each missing char.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i do not know yet exceptions handling....i am still learning stuff.... phrase1 = " I was walking down." , Your try...except code responds I'm not handling correctly the 'I' character .(i capital i mean) What is wrong with that 'I' character in the phrase1 ? (same same for the dot sign at the end)

Comment: You don't have them in your alphabet. You should either extend your alphabet with capital letters (or convert everything to small case by str.lower()) and define how to process interpunction characters (.,;: etc)