# Python AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'

Tags: python

I'm attempting to get the index of certain elements in some data. I want to find all the instances of 'b' and 'c', and put their indexes in 'position_b' and 'position_c'. Here is the code I've written and am getting the error with:

```
data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'c', 'c'], ['d', 'b', 'f'], ['g', 'c', 'i']]

position_b, position_c = [], []   
for line in data:
  if data.startswith("b"):
    position_b.append(line.index("b"))
  elif data.startswith("c"):
    position_c.append(line.index("c"))
```

As shown in the data above, some lines will not have b or c, and some lines will have both.

I initially tried just 'index', but that gave me the 'substring not found' error because some lists don't have 'b' or 'c'. Then I tried 'startswith' from the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22747092/valueerror-substring-not-found-what-am-i-doing-wrong), but that gives me the error 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith' ' I understand now that startswith does not work with list objects. What can I use instead to find and index the 'b' or 'c' in my lists?

Desired output:

```
position_b = [1, 0, 1]
position_c = [2, 1, 2, 1]
```

Comment: Lists don't have a startswith method. Consult the documentation for questions like this

Comment: Please remove everything not necessary to reproduce the error from the code. It seems really unlikely that `line.split()` returns `['a', 'b', 'c'] ['d', 'b', 'f'] ['g', 'c', 'i']` (what is that anyway? a string?), please provide accurate informations. In short provide an [mcve] (without `gzip`, `sys` and everything else not relevant for the exception you're trying to fix).

Comment: Is data a list of strings or a list of lists eg : `data = [ ['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'a'] ]` ?

Comment: A few people have the same suggestion, so I think I was mistaken - data must be a list of lists. It was generated using str.split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension` to achieve your task like this way:

I assume `data` variable is a list of lists like this way:

```
data = [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'a', 'a'], ['b', 'c', 'c'], ['d', 'b', 'f'], ['g', 'c', 'i']]
```

So, you can do this:

```
position_b = [(k,i) for k,v in enumerate(data) for i,j in enumerate(v) if j == 'b']
position_c = [(k,i) for k,v in enumerate(data) for i,j in enumerate(v) if j == 'c']

print("position_b:", position_b)
print("position_c:", position_c)
```

Output:

```
# position:   0, 1
#             v  v
position_b: [(0, 1), (2, 0), (3, 1)]
position_c: [(0, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (4, 1)]
```

**Edit**:

The whole `list comprehension` syntax can be written like this way using only `for loops` and `enumerate`:

```
position_b, position_c = [], []
for k,v in enumerate(data):
    for i,j in enumerate(v):
        if j == 'b':
            position_b.append((k,i))
        if j == 'c':
            position_c.append((k,i))

print(position_b)
print(position_c)
```

Output:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 0), (3, 1)]
[(0, 2), (2, 1), (2, 2), (4, 1)]
```

Comment: I'm having trouble puzzling through that list comprehension, could you break it down a little so I can better understand what's going on? When I try to break it into pieces I get 'invalid syntax' on my " if j == 'b' " line. This works though, thanks for helping!

Comment: Check now, i've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Although you expect to use `startswith`, it seems like you just want to know if the list *contains* a certain item, regardless its position. So you can just use the `in` keyword.

```
if "b" in data:
    position_b.append(line.index("b"))
```

Or:

```
try:
    index = line.index("b")
except ValueError:
    # line doesn't contain "b"
    pass
else:
    position_b.append(index)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I try the first option by adding position_b = [] in the beginning and print position_b at the end, the print statement just gives me empty brackets [] instead of the [1, 0, 1] I'm expecting. The second option only gives the index for the first instance of "b" in a list, where I'd like it to give [0, 1, 2] for a list like ['b', 'b', 'b'].